# Tabs for Android Studio (and other apps) on a Mac

Tags: android, tabs, new-project, android-ide

How to open new project same tab for Android Studio (and other apps) on a Mac

open to new project in same tab

Answer (score 2):

Go to Apple menu > System Preferences, then click General and set Prefer tabs: option to always.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From macOS 13 Ventura

Go to Apple menu > System Preferences, then click "Desktop and Dock",
scroll to "Windows and Apps" and set "Prefer tabs when opening documents": option to always.

[image]

See https://support.apple.com/de-de/guide/mac-help/mchla4695cce/mac